# Should I be using hidden fields to preserve model fields between Edit and Save in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC and am attempting to adhere to best practices.

I'm  creating an edit/save form for contacts using an existing data project with several classes I need to load and save together on one form.

For the contact, I need to load a Person's name, company details, phone #s, address fields, etc.. Each of these is a separate class in the data project, but I want to edit and save within one view/model. The issue is that I seem to have to put all the necessary PK and FK IDs on my view as Hidden fields, and it feels like there should be a better way to do it...

For my model, I use existing data class objects as the fields:

```
public class ContactEditModel 
{
     public Person PersonObjectName { get; set; }
     public Company CompanyObjectName { get; set; }
     public Address AddressObjectName { get; set; }
     ....
}
```

I instantiate an object for each of these and load them within my model, and I want to save any changes on submission of the Edit view.
Since I already have load and save methods for these classes (as well as stored procedures to do the work) in the existing data project, it seemed to make sense to re-use the code rather than specifying all the fields on the model and re-writing code.
However, without declaring all the hidden fields on the view, the IDs (person, company, address, etc.) aren't preserved in the model when saving, thus I have to specify each field I want preserved in a Hidden item.

The hidden fields code example is below:

```
     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PersonObjectName.ID)
     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PersonObjectName.Version)
     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PersonObjectName.CompanyID)
     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AddressObjectName.ID)
     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AddressObjectName.AddressTypeID)
     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AddressObjectName.Version)
     .....
```

Any ideas on a better way to do this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: are you using strongly type views?

Comment: Yes you need to use hidden files to keep bindings that are not being entered by the user.

Comment: Yes, this is a strongly typed view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this kind of question is always "it depends" and much of it is based on personal preference, or how you are doing things.

For instance, I prefer not to include all those ID's, but rather have a single parent id which I can then use to lookup the other ID's on POST.  This means you only need to save one hidden field (or even just have it be part of the url, so no hidden necessary).  In your case, probably the PersonObjectName.ID.

If you'd rather not do another lookup, then you can include those ID's, however you need to consider whether or not this is sensitive information.  For instance, what happens if someone uses Fiddler to change the Address id to something else?  You now have to add logic to ensure that the user isn't allowed to update addresses that are not linked to his id.

Answer (score 0):

For things like this I normally use TempData.
TempData is basically session, but its only available for one request.
So on the Edit get method I will put whatever IDs I need to store into TempData and then read them out when the form is posted.

Comment: What happens if the user is editing two items at the same time in separate tabs?  this creates a race condition in which one could overwrite the tempdata the other is expecting.  This is not a very good way to use tempdata.

Comment: oh, i use a unique name based on the record being edited. so my tempdata key would be [CompanyName:"currentEditedID"]

regarding the use of tempdata as a mechanism you don't have many options without posting the data to the client (which means its pretty much editable using firebug / fiddle). you have to store it server side. so you're left with session or something lighter like tempdata.

Answer (score -1):

You can follows the steps as follows:

Designing the model :

```
public class ContactEditModel 
{
 public string PersonObjectName { get; set; }
 public string CompanyObjectName { get; set; }
 public string AddressObjectName { get; set; }
 ....
}
```

Create strongly type views :

```
@model MyModels.ContactEditModel //Model Namespace
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PersonObjectName )
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CompanyObjectName )
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AddressObjectName )
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
    <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
}
```

Working with Action

```
public ActionResult Edit(ContactEditModel model)
{
     return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ContactEditModel model)
{
     // Implementation
     // model will have all updated values from UI
     return View(user);
}
```

Comment: Your answer does not address his question, and in fact it seems like you didn't read his question at all.